# Accurate time measurements when copying data via powershell

Tags: performance, powershell, time

Hi I have been trying to find a way to help me estimate how long it will take to move databases from one location to another. My online research has helped me through a few issues so far but I seem to be stuck because I have it using what seems to be the correct commands to see all files that would need to be counted but it comes back on a 5TB database as it will only take 22 milliseconds so either I have a faster network and server that I even knew or I screwed this up some how that I cannot see.

```
$item = get-childitem 'D:\SQL01' -Recurse
$d = "E:\SQL01"
$results = @()

$results = Foreach ($i in $item) {
Measure-Command -Expression {
Copy-Item -literalpath $i $d
    }
}

($results | Measure-Object -Property TotalSeconds -Sum).Sum


$results -f "c"
```

Reading over this it seems fine and it even returns a the sum of time but there is no way that is accurate. Please leave a comment if anyone sees where I did something wrong or you think there is something I could try differently.

Comment: `$CopyCmd = "Copy-Item -literalpath '$i' '$d'"` <-- this just assigns a string to a variable - it doesn't actually _do_ anything, which is why it only takes 22 ms ;-)

Comment: Thank you I took that out but it does still return 22 ms somehow.

Comment: You're still just _defining a string_. Remove the quotes if you want the `Copy-Item` statement to actually execute: `Copy-Item -LiteralPath $i $d`

Comment: I just tried that but it returns `$null ` I also tried removing the from copy item and removing recurse from the top variable and using `Copy-Item -Path $item -recurse -destintion $d` as well as subbing in `Move-Item` No luck yet though. I appreciate the help of course though.

Comment: "I have been trying to find a way to help me estimate how long it will take to move databases from one location to another...." This is over complicating things, what you might be looking for is [`Write-Progress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-progress?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: Oh! I did not know that command thank you very much. Let me try that instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of `Write-Progress` in action:

```
# Get all directories on D:\SQL01 recursively
$directories = Get-ChildItem 'D:\SQL01' -Directory -Recurse
# Set a destination folder
$destination = 'E:\SQL01'
$dirCount = $directories.count
$i = 0

foreach ($directory in $directories) {
    $progress = @{
        Activity        = 'Copying - {0}' -f $directory.FullName
        Status          = "Folder $i of $dirCount"
        PercentComplete = $i++ / $dirCount * 100
    }
    Write-Progress @progress
    Copy-Item -Path $directory -Destination $destination -Recurse
}
```